# What is heard when a tuning fork is struck?

Tags: frequency, geometry, harmonics, instrument, design

When a tuning fork is struck I hear two tones. From a distance I can hear a high octave frequency of the pitch of the tuning fork. Though, if I listen to it closely (closer to my ears), I also hear a lower octave frequency of the pitch of the tuning fork. I want to clarify that what I’m hearing is correct.

Also, is there something about “pure tones” that produces this effect, and if so what are the harmonics of a pure tone/tuning fork. Just from brief reading on the topic, I’ve seen it said that tuning forks overtone(s) (i’m assuming there is only one overtone) ring out quickly. Then why am I hearing a high octave version of the forks pitch and a low octave version of the forks pitch until it rings out?

Comment: Welcome Lecifer to Physics Stack Exchange. It is always helpful to give links to where you've "seen it said". It sounds like you are saying that what you are hearing is different from the ["clang tone"](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/tunfor.html). I suggest taking an audio spectrum with your phone using an app like [phyphox](https://phyphox.org/) or [Physics Toolbox](https://www.vieyrasoftware.net/) to see what frequencies you observe.

Comment: @DavidBailey Hi! & thanks for your welcoming. What i'm referring to is actually under the wikipedia for Tuning Fork - under description. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork#:~:text=When%20the%20tuning%20fork%20is,instruments%20with%20this%20pure%20tone. I do actually think what i'm referring to is the clang tone as i'm hitting the tuning forks together. I was just curious what the frequency of it is. The general consensus seems to be 6.00-6.30 but it is generally a perfect fifth from the pitch of the tuning fork correct? I'm not sure if its a perfect fifth or a minor sixth.